# Creating an animation from a bunch of .pdf files

Tags: video

I have histograms in a bunch of hundreds of .pdf files.

I would like to find a way to make an animation from these files to use in a Powerpoint presentation.

How can I do that ? It would also be great to be able to view the animation with Quicktime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

1. Join your PDF files: [How to merge pdf files in Mac OS X – CombinePDFs](http://www.techiecorner.com/218/how-to-merge-pdf-files-in-mac-os-x-pdf-merger/)
2. Convert your PDF to Keynote format: [PDF to Keynote](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/freesoftware/pdftokeynote.html)
3. Create your movie: [Exporting Keynote Presentation to QuickTime Compatible Movie File](http://www.usingmac.com/2008/9/24/exporting-keynote-presentation-to-quicktime-compatible-movie-file)

Later you can use your created .MOV in another Keynote presentation.